# How to count order number of values in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have an array with a few values and want to do something like this:

```
 $arrayvalues = array_reverse(explode(', ', somefunction()));
 foreach ( $arrayvalues as $arrayvalue ) :
           printf('<li class="'.$countvalue.'">'.$arrayvalue.'</li>');  
 endforeach;
```

I want to have in $countvalue the number of the value in the array

ie... the array will be something like this:  ("apple", "orange", "grapefruit")

I want the number to match the order number of these values 
apple = 1, orange = 2, grapefruit = 3

or actually even if it's just an incremental number according to the values echoed it doesn't matter, I just need to insert a css class represented by an incremembtal number

I tried playing $i... count... but I don't know how to achieve what I want; I'm more a designer than a coder, I looked in the PHP help but couldn't find a clear solution for my case

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop to iterate over your array, like so:

```
 for( $i = 0, $j = count( $arrayvalues); $i < $j; $i++) :
           printf('<li class="' . ($i + 1) . '">' . $arrayvalues[$i] . '</li>');
 endfor;
```

If you want the index `$i` to start at one, you need to add one in the printf statement.

Side note: You don't need printf here if you're not actually generating formatted output.

Comment: Syntax error: `endforeach` => `endfor`  I should -1 you for not testing the code you supply as an answer.

Comment: +1 for initializing $j and not counting the array in every step of the loop as most of coders those days

Comment: @LeviMorrison A -1 for that?! That's not nice... `;)`

Answer (score 4):

You already have an incremental number based on order. Keep in mind, this only works if your key's are 0-based. If you use an associative array you will need to use a `for` loop instead (as suggested by [nickb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8348147/191837)).

```
$arrayvalues = array_reverse(explode(', ', somefunction()));
foreach ( $arrayvalues as $key => $arrayvalue ){
    echo "<li class='$key'>$arrayvalue</li>";
}
```

Comment: This is what you should do. All the other answers so far are unnecessarily complicated, and complex code leads to buggy code. @LeviMorrison no he doesn't: "actually even if it's just an incremental number according to the values echoed it doesn't matter". The `$key` value is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Noted.  Also, printf is useless here.  I'd suggest `echo "<li class='$key'>$arrayvalue</li>";`  There's no point not to.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $arrayvalues = array_reverse(explode(', ', somefunction()));
 $i = 0;
 foreach ( $arrayvalues as $arrayvalue )
 {
           $i++;
           printf('<li class="'.$i.'">'.$arrayvalue.'</li>');
 }
```

Comment: regarding to Fulvio question your $i++; needs to be before printf('<li class="'.$i.'">'.$arrayvalue.'</li>');


`("apple", "orange", "grapefruit")
I want the number to match the order number of these values apple = 1, orange = 2, grapefruit = 3`

Comment: -1: I'm not going to advocate mixing `foreach` and a manual counter when his array is not associate.

Comment: @LeviMorrison - It's clean, works, and isn't a performance detriment. Sure, you can use a `for` loop, but you're just replacing `$arrayvalue` with `$arrayvalues[$i]`. I think this method is more intuitive.

Comment: any method will work. But @Fulvio wants to get the count of the array on his current code. so +1 for this

Comment: @LeysamRosario Supplying an answer where his code probably should be refactored anyway that doesn't support refactoring will get no support from me.  Since he wants numerical indices, he clearly DOES NOT HAVE an associative array.  Switch to using the proper construct for the task.

Comment: @LeviMorrison - Relax. There's no need to get so stressed out about (what you consider to be) a slightly imperfect answer.

Comment: @Polynomial If the person asking the question can't solve this simple task without help, then we should provide proper instruction, not just answer the question.  That's the only reason I care.  Also, as a point of interest, you may as well remove `$i++` and use `(++$i)` in the class.

Comment: @Polynomial : ++$i (I really like this operator) or (key($arrayvalues ) + 1). But why printf in this case? http://www.nutt.net/2004/12/09/php-benchmarking-echo-vs-print-vs-printf/

Comment: @narcisradu - I just copypasted the OP's code and modified it as little as possible so he'd understand it easily.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the effort, it was not absolutely necessary to use my own code (which is notoriously away from perfect), so I picked nickb/levi answer - thanks again though

Answer (score 0):

```
 $arrayvalues = array_reverse(explode(', ', somefunction()));
 $i=0;
 foreach ( $arrayvalues as $arrayvalue ) :
           ++$i;
           $countvalue = $i;
           printf('<li class="'.$countvalue.'">'.$arrayvalue.'</li>');  
 endforeach;
```

We (or I) advise you use a normal for loop.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayvalues); $i++) {
     printf('<li class="'.($i+1).'">'.$arrayvalue.'</li>');  
}
```